# Copy variable range from one sheet to another

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to copy data from a sheet "Inv_Headers", Column C, from 2nd row until the last row to a sheet "Customers", Column U, from 4th row.

```vb
Private Sub Invoice_C()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim lastrow As Long

    Set ws = Worksheets("Inv_Headers")
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("CUSTOMERS")
  
    lastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row ' last row in column C
    ws.Range("C2:C" & lastrow).Copy
    ws1.Range("U4").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    ws1.Activate
End Sub
```

My code is giving me

> msg '91' - Object variable or With block variable not set.

Comment: You called your first sheet ws, not ws1, so change the ws1 in: ws1.Range("U4").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Comment: @Absinthe oh, damn. Thank you! I haven't noticed.

Comment: Perfect example of why you should use `Option Explicit` for each module, and compile before running. This would immediately raise an error on line  `Set ws2=....`

Answer (score 1):

Based on check from @Absinthe, I've corrected the typo and here is the correct code:

```
Private Sub Invoice_C()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim lastrow As Long

    Set ws = Worksheets("Inv_Headers")
    Set ws1 = Worksheets("CUSTOMERS")


        lastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row ' last row in column C
        ws.Range("C2:C" & lastrow).Copy
        ws1.Range("U4").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        ws1.Activate


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Srpic's offering, I can remember not getting this part to work:
`ws.Range("C2:C" & lastrow).Copy`

you can fix it with `ws.Range("C2", "C" & lastrow).Copy`

If you start typing in Range() you will see that `,` is an acceptable separator, whereas `:` for an incomplete range assingment is not.

```
Private Sub Invoice_C()
Dim ws As Worksheet, ws1 As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Long

Set ws = Worksheets("Inv_Headers")
Set ws1 = Worksheets("CUSTOMERS")


    lastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row ' last row in column C
    ws.Range("C2", "C" & lastrow).Copy
    ws1.Range("U4").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    ws1.Activate
```

End Sub